# How can I use an Event Emitter to call a function that returns a value, and wait for the response before proceeding?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, events, components

So I want to emit an event from a child component that triggers a function in the parent component, but I want to wait to get a response from that parent function before proceeding.

Child

```
@Output() callParentFunction = new EventEmitter<any>();

...

this.callParentFunction.emit();
let tempVal = responseFromParentComponent; //How can I set this value?
//After parent function has returned a response, the next line of code should run
console.log("Response returned");
```

Parent

```
template: `
    <child-component
      (callParentFunction)="parentFunction($event)"
    >
    </child-component>
  `

...

parentFunction(){
    //This function calls an api, then returns the response
    [API call goes here]
    return response;
}
```

How can this event emitter be set up? Or is there a way to do it without event emitters?

Comment: You would do your logics in `parentFunction()` no?

Comment: @penleychan the child component still has logic it needs to do after receiving a response from the parent

Comment: In that case you should be using services to handle that via `BehaviorSubject` or `Subject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `parent-child` communication, I'd stick to using **setters** in order to do some stuff when a property changes.

#### child.component.ts

```js
@Input()
set response (v: any) {
 // Do some logic here
}

@Output() 
callParentFunction = new EventEmitter<any>();

doStuff () {
 this.callParentFunction.emit();
}
```

#### parent.component.ts

```js
public response$: Observable<IResponse | null> = of(null);

parentFunction(){
    this.response$ = this.http.get(/* ... */)
}
```

#### parent.component.html

```html
<child-component
  [response]="response$ | async" 
 (callParentFunction)="parentFunction($event)"
></child-component>
```

Comment: how can the child know that parent sent a response back to the child?

Comment: @chitgoks I think when the child's `response` setter has been called.